# html text not displaying in QTextBrowser (PyQt)

Tags: python, server, pyqt, client, qtextbrowser

I've written a simple browser program that displays html content in a QTextBrowser. In that html content I have a hyperlink and I want the hyperlink to open a different page (displaying the html content received from the server). So basically after the user types in "server" in the url box the server sends the client (the browser) some html data and then after it is displayed in the QTextBrowser the user can then click on the link. After clicking on the link the client requests another page. The server then fulfills this request by sending the html data and then the browser should dislay the html contents again. The problem with my code is that after the second request the html data is not displayed even though all functions are working correctly. What could be the problem?

```
class Browser(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Browser, self).__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('gui_browser.ui')

        self.csi_thread = Client_Server_Interactive_Thread()
        self.connect(self.csi_thread, QtCore.SIGNAL("display_html(QString)"), self.display_html)

        self.ui.txt_browser.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        self.connect(self.ui.txt_browser,
                 QtCore.SIGNAL('anchorClicked(const QUrl &)'),
                 self.anchorClickedHandler)

    def anchorClickedHandler(self):
        self.ui.txt_browser.setSource(QtCore.QUrl("html_file.html"))
        send_msg('link') # sends the server a request

    def display_html(self, data):
        temp_html_file = open('html_file.html', 'w')
        temp_html_file.write(data)
        temp_html_file.close()
        self.ui.txt_browser.setText(data)
        self.parse_document(data)

class Client_Server_Interactive_Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        socket_create()
        while True:
            msg = listen_for_msg()
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('display_html(QString)'), msg)
```